# The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, wcf-binding

I have tried implementing a number of suggestions from other questions to fix this frustrating issue. Normally, when I set up a site in IIS, the web apps are somewhat "agnostic" to what is going on at the transport layer. However, for this particular app, I cannot get it to work when I apply an https  binding.

My web.config looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultAPIBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and my Global.asax.cs looks like

```
 ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  //builder.Register<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
  builder.Register<IResourceFactory, Classes.LightCoreResourceFactory>();

  IContainer container = builder.Build();

  var configuration = HttpHostConfiguration.Create().SetResourceFactory(new LightCoreResourceFactory(container));  

  RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<WebServiceResources>("ws", configuration);
```

But whenever I add an `https` binding to my IIS site, I get the error:

```
The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: context.ListenUriBaseAddress

[ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: context.ListenUriBaseAddress]
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener..ctor(TransportBindingElement bindingElement, BindingContext context, MessageEncoderFactory defaultMessageEncoderFactory, HostNameComparisonMode hostNameComparisonMode) +12800194
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener..ctor(HttpTransportBindingElement bindingElement, BindingContext context) +41
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1..ctor(HttpTransportBindingElement bindingElement, BindingContext context) +28
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener(BindingContext context) +133
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener() +63
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Channels.HttpMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener(BindingContext context) +90
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener() +63
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Http.Channels.HttpMessageHandlerBindingElement.BuildChannelListener(BindingContext context) +158
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener() +63
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener(Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters) +125
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean supportContextSession) +336
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener& result) +716
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +1131
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +65
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen() +34
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +50
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +310
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open() +36
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +91
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +598

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/ws' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: context.ListenUriBaseAddress.]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +495736
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetRouteServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

Since the error message does not provide a location in my code to check or any other hints, and since I have already implemented some of the other suggestions on how to fix this, I am at a loss. Any idea of what I can do to make this app allow `https` bindings?

Comment: but you get a stacktrace? how about posting that.

Comment: sure thing... good point

Comment: "But whenever I add an https binding to my IIS site, I get the error:" can you clarify how you add an https binding to your IIS site? Through IIS itself or?

Comment: Through IIS itself, yes

Comment: I'd wager the problem is with the web.config file.  Are there more WCF-related line items in your web.config?  e.g. services, behavoirs, etc.  See here for a sample:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232.aspx  -- also I see you're going for client certificate security on the message itself..  Don't be alarmed any time I've dealt with such requirements it does take some tweaking to get working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what @thedr said, here is what we did:

1. Upgrade to MVC4 if you have not done so already
2. Add the following class ripped straight from [this CodePlex discussion](http://wcf.codeplex.com/discussions/260860)

> ```
> public class HttpsServiceHostFactory : HttpConfigurableServiceHostFactory
> {
>     public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>     {
>
>         var host = base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);
>
>         foreach (var httpBinding in from serviceEndpoint in host.Description.Endpoints
>                                     where serviceEndpoint.ListenUri.Scheme == "https"
>                                     select (HttpBinding)serviceEndpoint.Binding)
>         {
>             httpBinding.Security.Mode = HttpBindingSecurityMode.Transport;
>         }
>
>         return host;
>     }
> }
> ```

Then when you do `RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute`, it should look like

> ```
> RouteTable.Routes.
>         MapServiceRoute<WebServiceResources, HttpsServiceHostFactory>("ws", configuration);
> ```